# Normal vector of hypersurface in Schwarzshild spacetime

Tags: general-relativity

I've read that the following hypersurface is a null surface which means that the normal four-vector has a length of 0. I would however like to confirm this myself.

$$
2 M G \ln \left|\frac{r}{2 M G}-1\right| + t+r= B
$$

where $B$ is a constant and the surface is located in Schwarzshild spacetime.

**How do I compute the normal four-vector and its length?**

I suspect I should use the gradient to get a normal four-vector but what does the gradient look like here? Is it made up of partial derivatives or covariant derivatives?

**Update: use the metric tensor?**
It seems like the covariant derivative (which is used to get the four-gradient) reduces to the normal partial derivative in this case since it is a scalar function. Wikipedia says that

> In GR, one must use the more general metric tensor $g^{\alpha \beta}$, and the tensor covariant derivative
> ([en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-gradient))

Comment: The covariant derivative of a scalar function is just the normal derivative, and it's the normal vector by the same standard argument from multivariable calculus.

Comment: @Javier I don't think it's enough to only use the covariant derivative (which in this case is the normal partial derivative) in GR but I also need to use the metric according to wikipedia although they don't specify how. Do you know how I would compute the normal vector and its length?

Comment: "In GR, one must use the more general metric tensor g^{alpha beta} and the tensor covariant derivative" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your surface is defined implicitly by the equation $F(t,r,\theta,\phi) = B$.  The natural object which defines the orientation of the surface is not a vector but rather a covector $n_\mu$, with components
$$n_\mu = \partial_\mu F$$
The surface is null if $g^{\mu\nu} n_\mu n_\nu = 0$.  If you insist on talking about vectors, then you can "raise the index" on $n_\mu$ to find its vector partner given by

$$\tilde n^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} n_\nu = g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu F$$

The surface is then null if $g_{\mu\nu} \tilde n^\mu \tilde n^\nu = 0$.  Of course, going this route is pointless, because

$$g_{\mu\nu} \tilde n^\mu \tilde n^\nu = g_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\alpha} n_\alpha g^{\nu\beta} n_\beta = \delta^\alpha_\nu g^{\nu \beta} n_\alpha n_\beta = g^{\alpha \beta}n_\alpha n_\beta$$

so converting $n_\mu$ to a vector first and then computing the inner product from there amounts to just circling the block a few times.